# When to loop from 0 to end and when to loop from end to 0?

Tags: c#, for-loop

What are the scenarios in which you loop from 0 to the end of list(list or Map) and which scenarios you loops from end to 0?  Here is the code snippet that iterates through the list from 0 to end to filter out some specific student names .  Does this code throw any exception in any scenario? Does iterating from end of the list to zero make any difference to this code?

```
List<Dictionary<string, string>> allStudentsList = allStudentsArray.ToList();
for (int i = 0; i < allStudentsList .Count-1; i++) {
    Dictionary<string, string> student= allStudentsList .ElementAt(i);
    string studentName;
    bool hasValue = studentName.TryGetValue("id", out studentName);
    if (hasValue) {
        if (studentName.StartsWith("John") {
            allStudentsList.RemoveAt(i);
            i--;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Putting this as a comment as it's not related to your question but you should replace elementat(i) with simply indexing in the list. ElementAt is a linq operator so either it is optimized for list (and you're adding just a method overhead) either it doesn't have a list specific path and then it's causing a huge slowdown because it needs iterate the whole list everytime up to the index to find the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your question contains a semantical error. It is:

> From `end-1` to and including `0`.

If you start with `end`, you will immediately get an [`ArgumentOutOfRangeException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentoutofrangeexception(v=vs.110).aspx) because of the [`ElementAt`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299233%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method specifications.

If you move from *right-to-left*, you don't have to perform an increment (`i++`) in case the `hasValue` is true. Simply because the items on the left of the index are not shifted. So you can implement it as:

```
List<Dictionary<string, string>> allStudentsList = allStudentsArray.ToList();
for (int i = allStudentsList.Count-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    Dictionary<string, string> student = allStudentsList.ElementAt(i);
    string studentName;
    bool hasValue = studentName.TryGetValue("id", out studentName);
    if (hasValue) {
        if (studentName.StartsWith("John") {
            allStudentsList.RemoveAt(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Next it can make a difference in performance. If you remove an element from an [`List<T>.RemoveAt`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5cw9x18z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), it means all elements on the right of the index, are placed one place to the left. Now if you first remove from the right, the number of items on the right will be small, and furthermore the number of items to be shifted to the left will be smaller if the index is located near zero (simply because some elements have already been removed). But don't expect a huge performance boost if the `hasValue` only seldomly is `true`.

In this case it doesn't matter whether the `for` is done forward or backward, because there is "shared state" among the different iterations.

Comment: I have to disagree with your first two paragraphs, where you say that the OP's "question contains a semantical error". The OP uses the word "end" to describe the end of the list, not as an index variable. Specifically, the OP twice says "end of the list", so it's clear he (or she) is not using "end" as an index. So sayng it should be "end - 1" is like saying "this train goes to the end - 1 of the track".

Answer (score 1):

And now, I'd like to offer a *companion* answer to CommuSoft's most excellent and thorough prior comment. *(i.e.* "not related," but rather: "in parallel .. tangental .. 'FYI' ...")*

*In general* (and *regardless(!)* of the language being used ...), if you are iterating by-index through *any* sort of data-structure from which you are **removing** things, you *always* want to iterate "from end to 0." (Otherwise, it really doesn't matter ...)

Why?  Because, anytime you remove anything from any sort of collection, the 'length' of that collection decreases by 1.  *If* you are iterating from back-to-front, this is not a concern: you will never "miss anything," nor will you "encounter the same element twice." Both(!) of which are very-real (and so, "entirely avoidable") concerns if you are traveling the other way.

Comment: Small comment: it's not entirely true, for a *linked list*, iterating backwards will result in *O(n^2)* whereas iterating forward yields *O(n)* time complexity. Some Iterators/Enumerators offer remove features and in that case one can do inline removal...

Comment: I'm not entirely sure by what logic you conclude that "iterating a linked-list forward *vs.* backward" produces any sort of difference in O-cost at all. (Nevertheless, I graciously concede your point, without further comment, to be "undoubtedly, true.") My comments were, indeed, *specifically* directed to those cases in which "one's current-position within the collection" is expressed by an *ordinal,* not by (as is strictly the case with a "linked-list") a "pointer." I therefore see no conflict between our respective, valid, comments.